# Problem with auto-generated url alias when attempting to make a third-level menu item

Tags: navigation, path-aliases

Using [node:menu-link:parents]/[node:title] as the pattern for nodes in Url Aliases works fine for a menu that is only two levels, but if I attempt to assign a node to a third level under a menu, instead of getting top-level-node/2nd-level-node/third-level-node as the url alias, I get top-level-node-2nd-level-node/third-level-node as the alias. Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to auto-generate top-level-node/2nd-level-node/third-level-node when creating a menu item at the third level?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`/[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]/[node:menu-link:title]`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much!